# Covering for loops in test class that sends an email

Tags: apex, unit-test, singleemailmessage

I can't seem to figure out how to cover the portion of the class within the for loops. I'm not sure if there are additional things to add since it's sending an email.

```
public with sharing class conEmailChangeHandler {
public static void conEmailChangeHandler(List<Id> conId) {
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();   
    List<ts2__Placement__c> plcAcctPayList = new List<ts2__Placement__c>();
    List<ts2__Placement__c> plcTSAppList = new List<ts2__Placement__c>();
    List<String> userEmails = new List<String>();
    plcAcctPayList = [SELECT Id, Name, ts2__Accounts_Payable__c, jstcl__Accounts_Receivable_U__r.Email, ts2__Accounts_Payable__r.Name FROM ts2__Placement__c WHERE ts2__Status__c = 'Active' AND ts2__Accounts_Payable__r.Id = :conId];
    plcTSAppList = [SELECT Id, Name, jstcl__TimecardApprover__c, jstcl__Accounts_Receivable_U__r.Email, jstcl__TimecardApprover__r.Name FROM ts2__Placement__c WHERE ts2__Status__c = 'Active' AND jstcl__TimecardApprover__r.Id = :conId];
    
    if(plcAcctPayList.size() > 0){
        for(ts2__Placement__c plc : plcAcctPayList){
            String payrollRep = String.valueOf(plc.jstcl__Accounts_Receivable_U__r.Email);
            //initiallize messaging method
            System.debug(plcAcctPayList);
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage singleMail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            String[] toAddresses = new String[] {payrollRep};
            singleMail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
            singleMail.setReplyTo('no-reply@noreply.com');
            singleMail.setSenderDisplayName('Test');
            singleMail.setSubject('Contact Record Email Address has Changed : ' + plc.ts2__Accounts_Payable__r.Name);
            singleMail.setBccSender(false);
            singleMail.setUseSignature(false);
            singleMail.setPlainTextBody('The Billing Client Contact on ' + plc.Name +' has had their email address changed. Please advise.');
            singleMail.setHtmlBody('The Billing Client Contact on<b> ' + plc.Name +' </b>has had their email address changed. Please advise.<p>'
            singleMail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            emails.add(singleMail);
        }
    }
    if(plcTSAppList.size() > 0){
        for(ts2__Placement__c plc : plcTSAppList){
            String payrollRep = String.valueOf(plc.jstcl__Accounts_Receivable_U__r.Email);
            //initiallize messaging method
            System.debug(plcTSAppList);
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage singleMail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            String[] toAddresses = new String[] {payrollRep};
            singleMail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
            singleMail.setReplyTo('no-reply@noreply.com');
            singleMail.setSenderDisplayName('Test');
            singleMail.setSubject('Contact Record Email Address has Changed : ' + plc.jstcl__TimecardApprover__r.Name);
            singleMail.setBccSender(false);
            singleMail.setUseSignature(false);
            singleMail.setPlainTextBody('The Timecard Approver on ' + plc.Name +' has had their email address changed. Please advise.');
            singleMail.setHtmlBody('The Timecard Approver on<b> ' + plc.Name +' </b>has had their email address changed. Please advise.<p>'
    singleMail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            emails.add(singleMail);
        }
    }
    Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
  }
}
```

Test class:

```
public static testmethod void conEmailChangeHandlerTest() {
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();   
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage singleMail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator'];
    User u = new User(Alias = 'test1', Email='test@gmail.com',FirstName = 'Test', 
        EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testlast', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
        LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
        TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='test111@test.com');
    insert u;
    ts2__Source__c source = new ts2__Source__c(Name = 'LinkedIn.com - Resume Search');
    Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Express Scripts Holding Company');
    insert acc;
    Account acc2 = new Account(Name = 'Candidates- 10-2018');
    insert acc2;
    List<Id> conList = new List<Id>();
    Contact con = new Contact(FirstName='fnadddmes', LastName = 'lnamasdfdes', Email = 'emadi4ls@gmail.com', Phone = '9744800300', AccountId = acc2.Id, ts2__Source__c = source.Id, ts2__People_Status__c = 'Placed');
    Contact con2=new Contact(FirstName='fnamfafes', LastName = 'lnasdfames', Email = 'emai234ls@gmail.com', Phone = '9743800300', AccountId=acc.Id, Relationship_Status__c = 'Lunch'); 
    Contact con3=new Contact(FirstName='fnamfafesdsfa', LastName = 'lnasdfsdfames', Email = 'emai234sdfls@gmail.com', Phone = '9743850300', AccountId=acc.Id, Relationship_Status__c = 'Lunch'); 
    Contact con4=new Contact(FirstName='fnamfafesdsfa', LastName = 'lnasdfsdfames', Email = 'emai23asdfasdasfd4sdfls@gmail.com'); 
    insert con; insert con2; insert con3; insert con4;
    ADP_Department__c adp = new ADP_Department__c(Name = 'Georgia');
    insert adp;
    ts2__Job__c job = new ts2__Job__c(Name = 'Software Engineer',Hiring_Manager_Contact__c = con2.Id);
    insert job;
    ts2__HolidayCalendar__c hcal = new ts2__HolidayCalendar__c(Name= 'Holiday Calendar');
    insert hcal;
    Labor_Category__c lcat = new Labor_Category__c(Name='Software Engineer 1');  
    insert lcat;
    ts2__Placement__c plc = new ts2__Placement__c(ts2__Job__c = job.Id, Contractor_Type__c = 'Technical Youth', Onboarding_Method__c= 'Staff Augmentation', ts2__Start_Date__c= Date.newInstance(2019, 1, 7), ts2__End_Date__c= Date.newInstance(2019, 2, 15),
    jstcl__HireType__c= 'W2', ADP_Department__c= adp.Id, ts2__Bill_Rate__c= 60.00, ts2__Pay_Rate__c= 30.00, jstcl__Invoice_Batch__c= 'Placement', ts2__Client__c= acc.Id, ts2__Hiring_Manager__c= con2.Id, jstcl__TimecardApprover__c= con2.Id, jstcl__SecondaryApprover__c = con3.Id, jstcl__HolidayCalendar__c= hcal.Id,
    State_Worked_In_Non_TFI_Placements__c= 'GA - Georgia', ts2__Status__c ='Active', VMS__c = '', jstcl__Overtime_Bill_Rate__c= 60, jstcl__Burden__c= 20, ts2__Accounts_Payable__c =con4.Id ,jstcl__Accounts_Receivable_U__c= '00537000005d7F2AAI', jstcl__Terms__c= 'Net 60', ts2__Employee__c= con.Id, Labor_Category__c= lcat.Id);
    insert plc;

    test.startTest();

    con2.Email = 'test@gmail.com';
    conList.add(con2.Id);
    update con2;

    test.stoptest();
  }
}
```

Comment: `Messaging.sendEmail` can only be tested from an invocation point of view (DMLs) and not a content point of view. Something like `System.assertEquals(1, Limits.getEmailInvocations(), 'Timecard Approver email has not been sent');` would suffice for your unit test.

Comment: if you adopt a pattern like fflib UnitOfWork, then you can use ApexMocks and verify the construction of all of the email message properties - see this [blog entry](http://cropredysfdc.com/2017/10/23/apexmocks-and-email/)